# How to convert Array Object with keys to Arrays (No Keys)

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, angular6

I have array like this:

`0: {sabha_id: "Scarborough", sabha_type: 6, followup_id: 44}
1: {sabha_id: "Mississauga", sabha_type: 8, followup_id: 44}`

I need something like this:

```
 [ {sabha_id: "Scarborough", sabha_type: 6, followup_id: 44}, {sabha_id: "Scarborough", sabha_type: 6, followup_id: 44}]
```

Comment: What you *have*  is already what you *want*.

Comment: Your input does not look like an array, it's an object as it contains keys `0`, `1` etc. but it doesn't have a look of that too as there is no braces. Please paste the correct one and always make sure you provide proper input future onwards. It may help others too understand well and it's like you are benefiting yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

`Object.values(obj)`

to convert an object to an array.

In your case:

```
let data = {
  0: {sabha_id: "Scarborough", sabha_type: 6, followup_id: 44}
  1: {sabha_id: "Mississauga", sabha_type: 8, followup_id: 44}
};

let array = Object.values(data);
```

## Order of properties returned from Object.values()

Since there is some debate about the order of iteration of properties returned by `Object.values()` I will clarify.

**Since ES6 the order of properties return is ordered as per specification**

For..in uses `[[enumerate]]` which in turn uses `Reflect.ownKeys` which then in turn uses `[[OwnPropertyKeys]]` which is defined as:

> 9.1.12 [[OwnPropertyKeys]] ( )
>
> When the [[OwnPropertyKeys]] internal method of O is called the
> following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Let keys be a new empty List.
> 2. For each own property key P of O that is an integer index, in ascending numeric index order
>    a. Add P as the last element of keys.
> 3. For each own property key P of O that is a String but is not an integer index, in property creation order
>    a. Add P as the last element of keys.
> 4. For each own property key P of O that is a Symbol, in property creation order
>    a. Add P as the last element of keys.
> 5. Return keys.

Comment: Actually order is not preserved, it will be ordered by the integer keys. `Object.values({1:1, 3:3, 2:2}) = [1,2,3]`. Having said that, there's no way to get the exact order in the source and this is probably what the OP needs

Comment: here question is how to get array like this.

Comment: @JuanMendes I am trying to describe that the order of the keys will be preserved, meaning 0 will come before 1 etc. ;)

Comment: 1) "The Object.values() method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property values, [in the same order as that provided by a for...in loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)" 2) ["There is no guarantee that for...in will return the indexes in any particular order."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Array_iteration_and_for...in).

Comment: @Andy Iteration order is guaranteed for some years now. See my edit

Comment: i just need a values, i dont care about order

Comment: @tanmayparmar Do what I explained and everything should work

Comment: @AlexandrosPanagiotakis I realize it's guaranteed, I'm just saying it may not the same as source order

Answer (score 0):

To guarantee that the proper order is retained, convert it into an array-like object by giving it a `length` representing the number of own properties on the object.

Then you can use `Array.from` to convert it.

```js
var data = {
  0: {sabha_id: "Scarborough", sabha_type: 6, followup_id: 44},
  1: {sabha_id: "Mississauga", sabha_type: 8, followup_id: 44}
};

data.length = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(data).length;

var array = Array.from(data);

console.log(array);
```

Comment: This seems a bit of overkill. You are guaranteed to get the numerical properties in the correct order when using Object.values()

Comment: @AlexandrosPanagiotakis: There's no guarantee. It's a common point of confusion since there are some instances where newer methods make such guarantees, but `Object.values` still retains its ES5 semantics.

Comment: Order is guaranteed in ES6. Check my updated answer ;)

Comment: @AlexandrosPanagiotakis: Not sure you you reached that conclusion in your answer. The `for-in` definitely doesn't use *OwnPropertyKeys*, since `for-in` visits inherited properties, and *OwnPropertyKeys* only visits own properties. Also, *OwnPropertyKeys* visits non-enumerable properties, while `for-in` does not.

Comment: ...the `for-in` uses *[EnumerateObjectProperties](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-enumerate-object-properties)*, which states: *"The mechanics and order of enumerating the properties is not specified but must conform to the rules specified below."*

Comment: In the same paragraph (13.7.5.15 EnumerateObjectProperties) it is stated that "EnumerateObjectProperties must obtain the own property keys of the target object by calling its [[OwnPropertyKeys]] internal method." which is also later displayed in the NOTE a few lines below

Comment: @AlexandrosPanagiotakis: That describes how keys are fetched, but the order of enumeration is still implementation defined. Because the spec does not describe a required algorithm, and because the enumeration order is not defined, they can actually fetch keys using whatever algorithm they wish, as long as all the same keys are obtained and visited. The NOTE shows a conforming implementation, but not a required one.